# Merge 2 csv files using powershell append

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file called newuser.csv that is generated daily and it's written on top of the old csv file, I created a separate csv called newuser2.csv that I could use to update only the new data from the newuser.csv file.

Here is an example

**newuser.csv contains**

```
givenName   sn  description title
Angel   test    US Empliyee IT Support Contractor
James   test    US Empliyee IT Support Contractor   
John    test    US Empliyee IT Support Contractor
```

**newuser2.csv contains**

```
givenName   sn  description title
Angel   test    US Empliyee IT Support Contractor
```

newuser.csv over-written every day
newuser2.csv I created and I would like to pick up changes from the newuser.csv and update and enter those changes to newuser2.csv **append**.

I tried

```
@(Import-Csv C:\scripts\test\newusers.csv) + @(Import-Csv C:\scripts\test\newusers2.csv) | Export-Csv C:\scripts\test\newusers2.csv -Append
```

This did not work as it duplicates the data each time I run the script.

I would really applicate any help as this would save me so much time.

Comment: Remove `-Append` from the call to `Export-Csv` if you don't want to append :)

Comment: I basically don't want to create a new file each time, I want to update the previously created newusers2.csv file. Won't I use -Append for that?

Comment: `-Append` is for appending to an existing document. Use `-Force` if you want to overwrite the existing document every time :)

Comment: -force doesn't work either. It duplicates the same information rather than updating it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gentle point @MathiasR.Jessen is making, is that we think you are using the wrong word :-). There is different ways to combine data, Overwriting is the `-Force` parameter e.g.

**File1**

```
A
B
```

**File2**

```
C
```

**File1 Overwriting File 2**

```
A
B
```

Append is "adding to the end" e.g.

**File1**

```
A
B
```

**File2**

```
C
```

**File1 Appended to File 2**

```
A
B
C
```

The word I believe you *actually* mean is **Update**. e.g. I want to *update* the list of users from file1 with the changes in file2. There is no "easy" parameter to do this because it's a more complicated process. For example, you have to choose your "unique identifier" as in, what uniquely identifies the user in order for you to update the right row. Typically this is something like usernames. In this case, without usernames, you can't simply use `givenName` as your only unique identifier because there may be multiple people with the name "John". Instead you have to (at the very least) see if the user matches by `givenName` **and** `sn`. (EDIT: Can use employeeID as unique identifier)

In this case, I read in the users, updated lists, and loop through both to find users who are in *both* lists and **update** the user information. I then export the list.

```
#Master list
$Users = Import-Csv C:\scripts\test\users.csv

#Update list
$NewUsers = Import-Csv C:\scripts\test\newusers.csv

#Loop through each user and make changes
foreach($User in $Users){
    #Loop through new users
    foreach($NewUser in $NewUsers){
        #See if the user matches by employeeID
        if($User.employeeID -eq $NewUser.employeeID)){
            #Update User information
            $User.description = $NewUser.description
            $User.title       = $NewUser.title
        }
    }
}

#Export the updated list
$Users | Export-Csv C:\scripts\test\updatedUsers.csv -Force
```

Comment: Thank you! there is a unique identifier. That's employeeID. I didn't list it in the sample csv. If there is a unique identifier, how can I use this? employeeID will always be different for each user.

Comment: @Sam That simplifies things. Then you only have to change the `if` statement. I have made an edit to the Answer

Comment: so in your script, you exported to a third Csv file. In my example, I only have 2 csv file. One is the master list and the second CSV file is what I wanted to be updated. Also, i ran the script and It says 

#Export the updated list
$Users = Export-Csv "C:\scripts\test\updatedUsers.csv" -force
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Comment: Sorry, that `=` should have been a pipe `|` character instead :-). Updated. Yes the filenames are different just to help with general understanding what direction the updates flow. You can change them to anything else you want depending on what you want updated and what you do not. By adding the `-Force` parameter to the `Export-Csv` you will be able to overwrite the file.